# monitor is giving wrong size info to computer?

Tags: display, hardware-failure

I just bought some used monitors, and one of them is not working correctly. Computer see it as a 1024x1024 although its 1440x900. I dont see my taskbar and one side is simply cut to 1024. Is there something I'm missing or the monitor is screwed and I need to make refund?

I can't change screen resolution to bigger, and I tried it with various computers.

Answer (score 1):

Check the video cable, or try switching to the DVI-D connector. Installing drivers for the monitor manually may also help. If all else fails, you may be able to disable EDID (the display information interface) within your video driver software.